# log4j extras throwing log4j:WARN Failure in post-close rollover action - using SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using log4j extras to have a size based log rolling. this is a linux enivronment and the folder and log files have all the write and read permissions.
but still I am unable to root cause the issue wrt to failure.

```
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=${catalina.base}/logs/mylog.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX} %t %-20X{xyz} %-36X{xvg} %-5p %c] %m%n
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.RollingPolicy.maxIndex=10
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.RollingPolicy.minIndex=1
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern==${catalina.base}/logs/mylog.log.%i.zip
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.TriggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.TriggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=10000
```

after digging the log4j extras code, it looks like its failing at the renaming the files during the rollover. apparently the following method is returning false.

```
 /**
   * Rename file.
   * @param source current file name.
   * @param destination new file name.
   * @param renameEmptyFiles if true, rename file even if empty, otherwise delete empty files.
   * @return true if successfully renamed.
   */
  public static boolean execute(
    final File source, final File destination, boolean renameEmptyFiles) {
    if (renameEmptyFiles || (source.length() > 0)) {
      return source.renameTo(destination);
    }

    return source.delete();
  }
```

ref: [source file: FileRenameAction](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/companions/extras/tags/v1_0_rc1/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/rolling/helper/FileRenameAction.java)

please help me with the issue. 
How to find the error related to the returned false from renameTo method of File ?

Comment: Can you provide the actual error message/exception. Try running with -D log4j.debug=true it may provide some additional information

Comment: Hi, There was no new informantion in the debug enabled logs.

Comment: the logs looked like :

`log4j:WARN Failure in post-close rollover action
log4j:WARN Failure in post-close rollover action
log4j:WARN Failure in post-close rollover action
log4j:WARN Failure in post-close rollover action`

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466206/log4j-failure-in-post-close-rollover-action-using-timebasedrollingpolicy